# Scrolling mouse while dragging item in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, drag-and-drop

To simplify: I have application made with few kendo-tilelayouts that contains tiles with informations. Each tile is draggable ,and can be dropped in another tilelayout.Application is fully in TS. The problem is: when I dragg an item i lose ability to scroll with mouse (all other event listeners stop working as well for the duration of drag). Targeting tilelayouts that are lower or higher is a hindrance ,and because my app is compiled inside WPF app panning becomes tricky and very annoying.
Because of complexity of my project I cannot use JS to implement draging/droping. So I want to ask if there a way to implement scroll event that is above drag&drop, or if there is option to make panning the screen while holding an item more natural via changing the area on the screen that you must reach before view starts moving up or down (default area is very thin).
I would greatly appreciate if any of You have an idea that could result in enforcing any kind of movement of view while holding an item.

From what i had read this problem existed for some years now ,but all the posts got closed without solution ,or included some sort of JavaScript implementation with various result ,but in the past 2 years I didnt notice as much posts that describes this problem.
Im using (dragstart) and (drop)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.